# Highcharts: what is my chart not zoomable?

Tags: highcharts

I am new to Highcharts. I have a column chart. jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mddc/Lvfkv20y/5/

Here is the chart code:

```
$('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
            type: 'column',
            zoomType: 'x',
            panning: true,
            panKey: 'shift',
            resetZoomButton: {
                theme: {
                    display: 'none'
                }
            }
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories:["Option 1", "Option 2", "Option 3", "Other"]
    },
    yAxis: {
        plotLines: [{
            value: 0,
            width: 1,
            color: '#808080'
        }]
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Test',
        data: [["23.1%", 3], ["15.4%", 2], ["38.5%", 5], ["23.1%", 3]]        
    }]
});
```

I am trying to make it zoomable. However, the chart has no response when I click and select an area.

Thanks and regards.

Comment: Have you been curious enough to check the [api reference](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts)?

Comment: Jugal, I read some part of API, but not all of it. I have other charts with many datapoints. My initial thought was that something wrong is with my code, but I was unable to find it. The info in your response makes total sense. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add to @Ben Shi's answer, you do not have enough data. But enough being a subjective word, you can instruct Highcharts, how much is really enough.

Use the [`xAxis.minRange`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.minRange) configuration to override minimum how many data points should show on the chart, the default is *roughly* five points

> **minRange: Number**
>
> The minimum range to display on this axis. The entire axis will not be
>   allowed to span over a smaller interval than this. For example, for a
>   datetime axis the main unit is milliseconds. If minRange is set to
>   3600000, you can't zoom in more than to one hour.
>
> The default minRange for the x axis is five times the smallest
>   interval between any of the data points.
>
> On a logarithmic axis, the unit for the minimum range is the power. So
>   a minRange of 1 means that the axis can be zoomed to 10-100, 100-1000,
>   1000-10000 etc.

Generally a value of `1` would be sufficient in most cases

```
 xAxis: {
      minRange: 1
 }
```

If you want maximum zooming, set this to a `negative` number, setting to `0` would force the default behavior

[Override Min Range to allow more zooming @ jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jugal/o0nugdhd/)

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there is anything wrong with your code. You simply do not have enough datapoints for the zooming function to work. Try adding more datapoints and you should be able to zoom!